# MvcMiniProfiler not rendering any results for ajax requests in asp.net webforms site

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, mvc-mini-profiler

I have an asp.net site running `webforms`.
I want to add the miniprofiler to the site because of periodic sluggishness on the site.

If I just add the miniprofiler to a site not calling any ajax requests then it works fine.

However, if it is a page calling ajax requests then it doesn't render any chiclet.
When i look in firebug i can see that the miniprofiler doesn't get any http requests at all

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any javascript errors? you *should* actually get an extra chiclet per ajax request, in addition to the main page

Comment: no i cannot see any javascript errors..

Comment: further weirdness.. if i add start stop routines to global.asax then it doesn't do anything? but if i add it in the code it works (not with ajax)

Comment: after finding and looking at this sample http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/#git%2FSample.WebForms i can see my mistake was adding it to application_start instead og application_beginrequest.. now it works like a charm :)

Comment: maybe add that as an answer to your own question, then (there may be a time delay before you can do that, but it could be very useful to other users)